# Is it true that Google won't index my site if I do not use a FQDN?

Tags: seo, google, sitemap, www

I have personal blog, and in one week my site is still not indexed in Google Search.

I have submitted to Google Analytics and Google Search Console and it's still not indexed.

Then I read in their [sitemap guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap?visit_id=638019820916566528-2504720823&rd=1) that it says:

> Use consistent, fully-qualified URLs. Google will crawl your URLs
> exactly as listed. For instance, if your site is at
> https://www.example.com/, don't specify a URL as https://example.com/
> (missing www) or ./mypage.html (a relative URL).

Is it true that Google will not index my site because my website is missing `www` or does not use a FQDN? Why can't I not use `www`, because it would be my preference not to.

Comment: FQDN does not mean starting with `www.`. Your hostname is a FQDN if you want, that is not the issue. The paragraph you quote is just to tell you to use only one name for your site and be consistent with it. If you decided to use a name without `www` then it is fine, just use it as is.

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name , i need subdomain,domain name, tld ... where i can read FQDN does not mean starting with `www.` ? . .  also i have debug with https://search.google.com/test/rich-results , the problem is the server sent `x-robots-tag: noindex` , now i will do research why

Comment: It can take more than a week.  And if Google does not like something on your page, it may not index it.  Have you looked at the GSC ?  It will tell you when it was last crawled (if at all).  What does it say when you do a **URL Inspection**

Comment: @RohitGupta im new in seo, after URL Inspection all is okay, this is good tool, i never try it, thanks for it,anyway do u have suggest reference for me to learn a seo ?

another reply,, maybe i must wait more than a week again

Comment: If you submit it to **Bing** and especially **Yandex**, they will give more feedback about anything that is not quite right.  Google is often will not give a reason.

Comment: Yes "according to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name ", `example.com` is as much a FQDN as `www.example.com` is. I don't know where you get confused, but that is not the problem. The distinction comes when you are in some kind of local network where you can use short names like `intranet` where the full name (FQDN) would be in fact `intranet.corp.example.com`.

Comment: "where i can read FQDN does not mean starting with www. ?" Naming website with a `www.` prefix is a pure **convention** and absolutely not a technical requirement. This stems from an era long gone, where one website was one physical host and hence you needed a name for that computer, so `www` was logical. We are way past those considerations now and you can have your website on any name you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need www.

The important term in the statement you quoted is the word **if**. The statement only refers to *"if your URLs look like this, do not put them in the sitemap like that"*. That's it.

You could also interpret it like this:

> **if** your site is at https://example.com/, don't specify a URL as https://www.example.com/ (additional www) or ./mypage.html (a relative URL).

By the way, this is only a statement about sitemaps. Most small websites do not need a sitemap for Google to crawl and index them. A sitemaps does help. But it is not a requirement.